# how to exclude words in regex using Negative Lookahead?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, web-crawler, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to exclude a word from a sentence, but if the excluded word does not appear, the regex should keep searching for characters until the exclude word is found.

For example, lets suppose I have a list like this:

```
S.no    Vehicle    Status
1        car          sold
2        car          not sold
3        car          sold
4        car          Repair
```

I want to match all those cars which don't have a status of sold (they could be anything but sold) and I want it to catch the status too (if not sold)

I tried this regex:

```py
f"car(?!\s+sold)"
```

But how can I tell it to continue if it doesn't find the "sold" in the negative lookahead (but still search with that filter)

Comment: Did you mean for that to be a raw string (`r"..."`)? Regex patterns should be raw strings.

Comment: We'll need to see the rest of your Python code if you want us to help

Answer (score 1):

You can write the pattern like this:

```
pattern = r"\bcar\b(?!\s+sold\b).+"
```

**Explanation**

- `\bcar\b` Match the word car
- `(?!\s+sold\b)` Assert not 1+ whitespace chars followed by the word "sold" to the right
- `.+` Match 1+ chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iNdU3p/1).

If there has to be a non whitespace char present after "car" and you don't want to cross newlines:

```
\bcar\b(?![^\S\n]+sold\b)[^\S\n]+\S.*
```

See another [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WMgLB5/1)